# MSSQL select lowest but not NULL/zero value from 25 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 25 (numeric) columns in one table in MSSQL and I need select lowest value, but not NULL or 0 value.

Columns are named like "%_price" (aaa_price, bbb_price, ccc_price...).
Some columns contains 0 or NULL value.

Example:

```
table (aaa_price, bbb_price, ccc_price, ddd_price, eee_price, fff_price)
value (NULL,      0,         324.23,    162.50,    NULL,      1729.72  )
```

Right result:
**162.50**

I can use some "brute force" method like:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN Col1 <= Col2 AND Col1 <= Col3 AND Col1 <= Col4 AND Col1 <= Col5 THEN Col1
    WHEN                  Col2 <= Col3 AND Col2 <= Col4 AND Col2 <= Col5 THEN Col2
    WHEN                                   Col3 <= Col4 AND Col3 <= Col5 THEN Col3
    WHEN                                                    Col4 <= Col5 THEN Col4
    ELSE                                                                      Col5
END AS [Min Value] FROM [Your Table]
```

But its insane with 25 columns... is there any better solution?

Thank You!

Comment: Seems like you're the victim of a poor table design.

Comment: SQL Server lacks built in support for scalar min/max (which other databases like MySQL and SQLite do in fact support).  Get ready for an ugly query, or maybe you can write a UDF to help you here.

Comment: You could `UNPIVOT` first such that data of the same "type", such that you want to query it, all appears in a single column. You could then also give a *name* to the column that comes into existence to store the *data* that has been mismodelled and stored in the column names (e.g. `aaa`, `bbb`, etc)

Comment: It's mainly a lot of cut&paste&modify, but you also got NULLs, so don't forget about `COALESCE/IFNULL` :-)

Comment: Your table design is wrong. Fix it before you add 25 moar columns.

Comment: I know, but it's old design (about 4+ years) and its implemented in too many SQL ...incredible hard to change it :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cross apply` can be good option in this case:

```
select
    *
from
    myTable
    cross apply (select 
                    minVal = min(val) 
                from (
                    values (aaa_price),(bbb_price),(...)
                ) t(val) where val > 0
    ) q
```

Edit:
You have to use dynamic SQL if you want to get column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table.

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
declare @cols varchar(8000)

select @cols =
    stuff((
        SELECT 
            ',(' + COLUMN_NAME + ')'
        FROM 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE 
            TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' 
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' 
            AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%price'
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '')

set @sql = 'select
                *
            from
                mytable
                cross apply (select 
                                minVal = min(val) 
                            from (
                                values ' + @cols + '
                            ) t(val) where val > 0
                ) q'

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works!
Is there any way to use dynamic columns (aaa_price),(bbb_price),(...)?

I can get the column names I need for example like this, but it does not work after you have been put into your SQL:
SELECT COLUMN_NAME as colName
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_price'

Comment: That is not supported. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [dynamic SQL statement](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx) and execute it in the following form

```
declare @tablename sysname = 'MultipleNumericColumns'
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 

select @sql = isnull(@sql + ' union all ','') + '
SELECT ' + name + ' as colname from ' + @tablename  
from sys.all_columns 
where 
    object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)

set @sql = '
select min(colname)
from (
' + @sql + '
) t
where colname > 0'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

You can realize that first I get the column names from system view

You can exclude columns that you don't want or use a pattern like name like '%price% etc at this step

Then I build a dynamic SQL query into a string variable as sql command
Please note that I use WHERE clause for greater than 0, etc

Final step is execution with EXECUTE command

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT Min(VALUE)
FROM (
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3...
    FROM YourTable

) t
UNPIVOT (VALUE FOR ITEM IN (Col1, Col2, Col3...)) u
WHERE VALUE != 0
```